# render image in .org file after creating its link

Tags: org-mode, images, rendering

After I insert this link into an .org file, it looks like a link:

```
[[./relative_path/rock.jpg]]
```

Is there a convenient way to render the image?

Opening and closing Emacs renders the image, but it's not very convenient.
revert-buffer function doesn't render the image.

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs.

Comment: Does `org-toggle-inline-links` (C-c C-x C-v) help?

Comment: Yes, except the function's name is org-toggle-inline-images.  Juancho, make your comment into an answer, or I will make the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `org-toggle-inline-images` (bound to <kbd>C-c C-x C-v</kbd>) will toggle (and thus refresh) the display of linked images.